# Passing an array within a controller and action from Zend Framework to a location.href extjs

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, zend-framework

I'm doing a project with a backend made with zend framework and a front-end made with extjs.

My problem is that after a user gridpanel is loaded and i press the edit icon to edit a user, I cannot used `location.href` to redirect to the edit section because I don't know how to send the info of the user ID in the way that zend framework controller recognize it.

this is the line of code i have

```
location.href = "< ? php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'edit','id'=>$id)) ?>";
```

this line of code is inside a actionColumn in the php way. I have a function with extjs to take the id of the user that i want to edit, but i don't know how to store it in the `$id` php variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a misconception. With Javascript, you cannot pass variables to php. In ExtJs even more, everything is done in the client and you have to load the data asynchronously through ajax.

Now in ExtJs, it would make little sense to load a new page from the server to edit a row in a grid. If you've done things correctly, this grid is bound to a store, that contains the users data. After you edited it, you save the changes to the server.

Now to answer your question : in the handler of the action column, the current record is passed to the function. See doc

```
handler: function (view, row, column, item, e, record) {
    $id = record.getId()
}
```

$id is now the user's id.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Lorenz. yes i understand what you mean, JS execute in the client. yes the data is in a Store and this data is load using a ajax proxy from some url with a basic auth header. i capture the id value this way,

```
<script>

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        //model: 'Contactos',
        //pageSize: 25,         
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url:  'https://app.alegra.com/api/v1/contacts/',
            method: 'GET',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                id: 'id'
                },
            headers: {
                Accept : 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Basic something'
                    }               
            }
        });





    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        title: 'Contactos',
        id: 'cat_categoriesGrid',
        store: store,
       // bbar: pagingToolbar,
        columns: [
                  { text: '#', dataIndex: 'id', width: 35 },
                  { text: 'Nombre', dataIndex: 'name', width: 210},
                  {text: 'Identificacion', dataIndex: 'identification',width: 210},
                  {text: 'Telefono 1', dataIndex: 'phonePrimary',width: 210},
                  {text: 'Observaciones', dataIndex:'observations',width: 210},
                  {
                        text: 'Acciones',
                        width: 210,
                        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        items: [{
                                icon: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl('image/page_edit.png');?>', // Use a URL in the icon config
                                tooltip: 'Edit',
                                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, a, b, c) {
                                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

                                    var id = rec.get('id');                                             

                                    location.href = "<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'edit','id'=>$id)) ?>";
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    icon: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl('image/delete.png');?>', // Use a URL in the icon config
                                    tooltip: 'Delete',
                                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, a, b, c) {

                                        }
                                    },

                        ]
                    }
              ],
        width: 1100,
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:15px;',
        enableColLock:false,
        //selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false}),
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

in extJS and yes the edit part should get me to a new page and load the data i will edit, but what i dont know is how? i have a ZEND controller and i dont know how to reach it with extjs, my idea was to echo the line above inside a handler so i can get that new page but i cannot put the " var id" inside that echo. So if a cannot do that how can i reach the Zend framework controller from extjs?

this is my controller on Zend F

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {

public function init()
{

}

public function editAction()
{

    // action body
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');        
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://app.alegra.com/api/v1/contacts/'.$id);
    $client->setAuth('admin', 'password');

    //se solicita un request con los parametros que se estan pasando en client
    $a = $client->request('GET');
    $b = strstr($a, '{');
    $json_alegra = substr($b,0, -5);

    //Se pasa de json a array
    $phpNative = Zend_Json::decode($json_alegra); //$phpNative = json_decode($json_alegra, true);

    //$this->view->response = $a;

    $this->view->form = new Application_Form_Alegraform();
    //usamos populate para llenar el formulario con el array $phpNative
    //las variables del array deben cooncordar con las del form
    $this->view->form->populate($phpNative);
    $this->view->form->setAction($this->view->
      url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'update','id'=>$id)));

}
```